# Выполнение класса в JButton

Tags: java, gui

Есть класс, который выполняет определенные действия и в итоге созадёт текстовые log-файлы. Возможно ли создать JFrame с JButton и JTextPane и назначить JButton выполнение класса и после выполнения этого класса вывести содержимое этих log-файлов в JTextPane?
Буду благодарен хоть за какую-то информацию , ибо идентичных задач не находил.

Comment: Да, это возможно. Эта задача состоит из задачи назначения обработчика кнопки и задачи чтения из файла. В Интернете сотни примеров того и другого.

Comment: не совсем понятно, в чем ваша проблема? Довольно тривиальная задача... Создали класс, унаследовались от JFrame, добавили два компонента - JButton и JTextPane, повесили на кнопку слушатель. Слушатель отследит нажатие на кнопку, соответсвенно, будет возможность запустить логику вашего класса, а возвращенный результат вывести на JTextPane